# Python. Parse csv file. Append value to the previous row if the next row has the same ID

Tags: python, csv, data-cleaning, data-preprocessing

I have a CSV file of around 8000+ rows and 2 columns:

```
userID     bookTitle
1123       book title 1
1123       book title 2
1123       book title 3
54         book title 2
776        book title 7
776        book title 1
```

I need it to be transformed to:

```
1123, book title 1, book title 2, book title 3
54, book title 2
776, book title 7, book title 1
```

meaning that each row is a user with its historical borrowings

Comment: Post what you managed to achieve in your code thus far?

Comment: Note: adding commas between your title would mean it would need to be quoted otherwise it will be read in as different columns (without a matching header)

Answer (score 0):

you could try something like this :

```
import csv
from collections import OrderedDict
from pprint import pprint
with open("test.csv") as csvfile:
    spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = ",")

    firstLine = True
    #d = OrderedDict() # if orderer important
    d = dict()
    for row in spamreader:
        if firstLine:
            firstLine = False
            continue
        d.setdefault(row[0], [])
        d[row[0]].append(row[1])

for k,v in d.items():
    print ",".join([k] + v)
```

Result:

```
54,book title 2
1123,book title 1,book title 2,book title 3
776,book title 7,book title 1
```

Answer (score 0):

My Python 3 version, as I wrote it before I saw you already had an answer...

```
from collections import defaultdict

# Use a defaultdict so we don't need to worry about
# initialising the value of each key
result = defaultdict(list)

# The reader
# Input is like:
# userID     bookTitle
# 1123       book title 1
# 1123       book title 2
# 1123       book title 3
# 54         book title 2
# 776        book title 7
# 776        book title 1 
with open("myfile.csv") as fp:
    for line in fp.readlines():
        if line.startswith("userID"):
            # Ignore the first line
            continue
        else:
            parts = line.split()
            # The key is the first value, the rest of the
            # values constitute the book title.
            result[parts[0]].append(" ".join(parts[1:]))
           
# The printer   
# Output should look like this:
# 1123, book title 1, book title 2, book title 3
# 54, book title 2
# 776, book title 7, book title 1
for key, value in result.items():
    print(', '.join([key] + value))
```

This is basically the same strategy as @baskettaz used, i.e. build a dictionary and then print it out in the desired format.

Answer (score 0):

A standard Python `defaultdict(list)` can help here to build up titles with the same ID.

```py
from collections import defaultdict
import csv

books = defaultdict(list)

with open('books.csv') as f_input:
    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input)
    header = next(csv_input)
    
    for row in csv_input:
        books[row[0]].append(row[1])

with open('updated.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_output:
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)
    csv_output.writerow(header)
    
    for user_id, titles in books.items():
        csv_output.writerow([user_id, ', '.join(titles)])
```

**How does this work?**
For each row that is read in, append the new title to a list associated with each ID in the dictionary. The `defaultdit(list)` helps you as you don't have to first ensure there is an empty list to append to.

So as you read the rows in, you would build up a dictionary looking like:

```py
{
    '1123' : ["book title 1", "book title 2", "book title 3"],
    etc...
}
```

After reading all the rows in, this can then be written out to another CSV file.

The output `updated.csv` file would contain:

```
userID,bookTitle
1123,"book title 1, book title 2, book title 3"
54,book title 2
776,"book title 7, book title 1 "
```

Note: the extra quotes are correctly added for the book titles as there are commas between entries. These quotes are automatically removed again when a CSV reader sees them.